# Рекурсивные вычисление всех возможных сумм n чисел

Tags: c++, c, рекурсия

Здравствуйте, я нахожусь на начальном этапе изучения программирования, и у меня возникла проблема. Мне необходимо вычислить все комбинации возможных сумм  n элементов, при это нужно использовать рекурсию. Язык c/c++.
 Например есть массив чисел: 2, 3, 5, 1. Через рекурсию нужно реализовать все возожные комбинации сумм. 
2+3
2+3+5
2+3+5+1
2+1
3+1 
И так далее.

Comment: Для начала давайте вы попробуете что-нибудь реализовать, затем выложите сюда свой код (даже если он будет делать совсем не то), и вот тогда мы вас направим в нужную сторону и поможем. Просто это ведь не общество решения задач за людей, а место, где помогают резрешить вопрос при условии, что человек пытался.

Comment: Не написав ни строчки кода вы всё равно ничему не научитесь, для начала попытайтесь сделать что-то сами. Изучение языка без практических усилий невозможно.

Comment: В том и дело, что мне нужна только идея алгоритма, я не прошу реализовать за меня.

Comment: @HatmZull, вы можете, например, создать массив, такого же размера, как и ваш изначальный. Записывать в качестве значений сначала 0 (и далее вызов рекурсии) потом 1 (снова вызов рекурсии). Когда глубина рекурсии достигнет размера массива, то там, где 1 - учитывайте в построении суммы.

Comment: Вот идея: 1. Простой вариант 2 числа, 2. Если чисел n > 2, то перебираем суммы A[n] + A[n-1], A[n] + A[n-2] ... A[n] + A[0], потом вызываем этот же цикл для n -1 и опять перебираем суммы. Заканчиваем рекурсию когда n == 2

Answer (score 1):

Ну, тебе нужно перебрать все подмножества этого множества.

Чтобы перебрать все подмножества, можешь воспользоваться следующей идеей:
Сделаем текущую сумму элементов на префиксе параметром рекурсии.
На каждом шаге рекурсии, если еще не все элементы рассмотрены, можно либо взять, либо не взять текущий элемент (i-ый) (взять то есть прибавить к сумме).
Когда элементы перебраны, у тебя уже будет готовая сумма.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответ. Пока писал вопрос, возникла такая идея: при сортировке слиянием делить массив, а потом уже складывать элементы.

```
int recsumms(int arr, int right,int left) {
    int middle = (left + right)/2;
    if (left==rigth) return arr[left]
    else 
    return recsumms(arr,left,mid)+recsumms(arr,mid+1,rigth)
}
```

Исправьте, если что-то не так.

Comment: Как-то у вас `int arr` не очень похож на массив. Вы уверены, что ваше решение верное, т.к. выглядит оно ну очень странно? Вам же предложили вариант с перебором всех подмножеств данного множества (ну по факту вам нужно найти [сочетания](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

Answer (score 0):

То, что вам нужно - это генерация всех кортежей, с которой начинается раздел 7.2 тома 4А "Искусства программирования" Кнута.

Рекурсивно - просто и непритязательно: если вы в состоянии построить все кортежи из `n` элементов, то все кортежи из `n+1` элемента получаются из имеющихся путем добавления к ним их же, но с `n+1`-м элементом (удвоение на каждом шаге), так что получается корректное общее количество - `2^n`. Построить все кортежи из нуля элементов сумеете? :) Впрочем, немного другими словами вам это уже подсказывали.